# MySQL: Правильно обновить данные после вставки

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При вставки записи (с приложения/клиента), я заполняю поле «date».
**Вопрос**:
Существует возможность атоматом (на стороне сервера) как-нибудь заполнить поле «year_month» (тип INT), после заполнения «date»? если в этом поле должно отображаться «месяц» и «год» (введенного в «date»), если триггером этого сделать не выходит.
Или всетаки это должен делать клиент.

Спасибо.

Comment: Это поле в БД вообще не нужно. потому как его значение всегда можно вычислить с помощью DATE_FORMAT на стороне MySQL и показать

Comment: Я знаю... еще есть функции "year" и "month" (для разбивки на год и месяц). Мне нужно поле «year_month», для вывода на страничку "Архива" данных, где отображается только "год" и "месяц", и потом легче делать выборку (для показа),  данных за месяц, Т.е. соответствующую ссылку делать на страничке

Comment: А чем хуже `select *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') as year_month from table`, чем просто `select *`. В конце концов можете сделать view: `create view MyView as select *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y') as year_month from table` И когда надо выводить данные на экран просто делать `select * from MyView` - вы получите данные из view как будто эта колонка действительно есть в таблице

Comment: C view, это хорошо, но я работаю с framework, и формировать условие выборки в view (html) не очень хотелось. А так у меня уже есть сформированный массив, который я вывожу в html, элементом которого есть "год" и "месяц", и который (в случае чего) я передаю в адресной строке для получения периода в один месяц, например "201608" - статьи за август 2016 года

Comment: Создавая дополнительный столбец, вы денормализуете базу данных. `view` в данном случае - представление базы данных.

Comment: Mike@ Да, **спасибо**, с "View" получилось. Только еще одно, "view" - должно быть в БД на постоянной основе, или его нужно все время создавать, читать от туда данные, а потом опять "убивать"?